# flutter aar file does not give classes in lib

Tags: android, ios, flutter, aar

recently im asked to develope a flutter project and release a *flutter sdk* in order to use it in native android and native ios projects.
i have already used **flutter build aar** command to build an aar file to use it in android projects but that aar file does not create classes that i had created in flutter lib folder.it only give access to classes in android module.
how to create an aar file inorder to access calsses in **lib**.is it possible?

for example i have this simple class in flutter\lib folder and want to use its method in another project as aar file.

```
class MobileNumberEntry  {

  void registerNumber(String mobileNumber)  {

  }

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem too